# How can I get Quarkus Swagger to recognize JsonSerialize(as=), JsonDeserialize(as=)

Tags: swagger, quarkus

I'm using Quarkus 1.10.3.Final (including quarkus-resteasy-jackson and quarkus-smallrye-openapi) and the Immutables library (org.immmutables:value:2.8.8) to define various application models.  My problem is the Swagger UI doesn't seem to recognize the standard jackson @JsonSerialize(as=) and @JsonDeserialize(as=) annotations.

In the model example defined below, I expect to see four (4) fields in the components section of the Swagger UI page.

#### Model Example

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonDeserialize(as = ImmutableFieldMetaData.class)
@JsonSerialize(as = ImmutableFieldMetaData.class)
@Value.Immutable
public interface FieldMetaData {
  String field();
  String type();
  Boolean deprecated();
  String description();
}
```

When looking at the Swagger UI page, however, the resulting component shows up as an empty object:
[image]

This issue in Swagger UI was addressed in version [1.5.14](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/pull/3264) of Swagger UI, then subsequently dropped as of Swagger UI 2.0, then fixed again in [2.1](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/pull/3043).

After all that lead-up, my question is simple:

- Short of abandoning Immutables, does anyone know of a work around?

Comment: Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post)

Comment: How do you generate the OpenAPI definition? Are you using the `quarkus-smallrye-openapi` maven dependency?

Comment: Are you using `quarkus-resteasy-jackson` or `quarkus-resteasy-jsonb`? While quarkus provides json-b (de-)serialization through jackson, the interface differs and the immutables library only claims compatibility with jackson.

Comment: I am using quarks-smallrye-openapi and quarkus-resteasy-jackson.

Answer (score 1):

After diving into the source code of smallrye-openapi, you can add the @Schema annotation to each Immutables field, i.e.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonDeserialize(as = ImmutableFieldMetaData.class)
@JsonSerialize(as = ImmutableFieldMetaData.class)
@Value.Immutable
@Schema(implementation = ImmutableFieldMetaData.class)
public interface FieldMetaData {
  String field();
  String type();
  Boolean deprecated();
  String description();
}
```

You can also just annotate the fields as @Schema if desired.

Comment: you saved my day! I wanted to Value Objects that I wanted to show as Strings in the OpenApi. Just adding `@Schema(implementation = String.class)` over the Value object class makes it appear as string in Swagger/SpringDoc OpenApi